# how to get agent/node name in jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

In jenkinsfile, I have a parallel logic that runs on several nodes, how can I get the agent's name on which the code is being executed on?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the `NODE_NAME` environment variable to fetch the Agent name within the Jenkinsfile. Here is a simple example:

```
node('master') {
    stage('GetNodeName') {
    def node_name = "${NODE_NAME}"
    echo "The Node Name is: ${node_name}"
    }
}
```

[image]

[Here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables) is the link to all the Environment Variables